# write 500 error into syslog and set custom error message in slim framework

Tags: php, slim

I'm setting up slim and want to write 500 error into syslog and set custom message for user. I've made custom logwriter that will write error into syslog. here is the implementation:

```
include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Slim\Slim;

$config = array(
    'debug' => false,
    'mode' => 'development',
    'log.writer' => new \api\libraries\LogWriter(),
    'log.enabled' => true,
    'log.level' => \Slim\Log::DEBUG
);

$app = new Slim($config);

/**
 * test
 */
$app->get('/test/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name2";
});

$app->run();
```

that will trigger an error and write error into syslog because variable $name2 is undefined. syslog sample:

```
agan@darkstar ~ $ sudo tail /var/log/syslog
Sep  9 11:37:46 localhost apache2: [API] ERROR - 2015-09-09T11:37:46+07:00 - exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: name2' in ...
```

then, i want to set custom message for user. so i add this code before `$app->run()`

```
/**
 * 500 internal service error handler
 */
$app->error(function(\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    $app->response->setBody('Sorry, we are offline');
});
```

how ever, if I add codes above, log writer is not been executed, no log is found in syslog, but custom message works properly.

how is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write to the log manually:

```
$app->log->error($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: could you explain little please, why the logger should  be called manually?
thank you btw.

Comment: The logger is not only for errors, you can use it to write *anything* into the log. Also, if the logger would be called automatically how would you prevent sensitive data appearing in the log files?